# does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject custom Model

Tags: magento2, module, collection

Here's my code

when I try to make the collection with my custom model I have this error

**In Collection.php line 612:**

**Easysoft\Logistic\Model\Tracking does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject**

app/code/Easysoft/Logistic/Helper/Shipup/Track.php

```
<?php


namespace Easysoft\Logistic\Helper\Shipup;


use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as OrderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory;
use Easysoft\Logistic\Model\ResourceModel\Transcan\Tracking\CollectionFactory;


class Track extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const FORMAT_DATE = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';//set format as per your requirement
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $order **/
    protected $orderFactory;   
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory **/
    private $dateTimeFactory;
    /** @var CollectionFactory $trackingCollection **/
    protected $tracking;

    public function __construct(
      OrderFactory $order,
      DateTimeFactory $dateTimeFactory,
      CollectionFactory $trackingCollection)
    {
        $this->dateTimeFactory = $dateTimeFactory;
        $this->orderFactory = $order;
        $this->tracking = $trackingCollection;
    }

    public function fillDeliveredAtFromShipup()
    {
        $dateModel = $this->dateTimeFactory->create();

        $collection = $this->tracking->create();
        foreach($collection as $item)
        {
        }
}
```

app/code/Easysoft/Logistic/Model/Transcan/Tracking.php

```
<?php
namespace Easysoft\Logistic\Model\Transcan;

use Easysoft\Logistic\Model\ResourceModel\Transcan\Tracking as TrackingResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Tracking extends AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(TrackingResourceModel::class);
    }

}
```

app/code/Easysoft/Logistic/Model/ResourceModel/Transcan/Tracking.php

```
<?php
namespace Easysoft\Logistic\Model\ResourceModel\Transcan;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;


class Tracking extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('easysoft_logistic_transcan_tracking', 'tracking_id');
    }

}
```

app/code/Easysoft/Logistic/Model/ResourceModel/Transcan/Tracking/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Easysoft\Logistic\Model\ResourceModel\Transcan\Tracking;

use Easysoft\Logistic\Model\Tracking as TrackingModel;
use Easysoft\Logistic\Model\ResourceModel\Transcan\Tracking as TrackingResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(TrackingModel::class, TrackingResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is this Easysoft\Logistic\Model\Tracking code. Please add it.

Comment: Please Review your model - refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244589/found-this-error-does-not-extend-magento-framework-dataobject